# Docker MariaDB Container fails importing data

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, macos-sierra

I am having trouble running my docker-compose.yml on my macbook (macOS 10x - 8GB - 2.4 GHZ). Everything works fine till the docker-entrypoint.sh wants to import the DB I am giving (900MB Mysql dump).

```
sw_mysql_1  | ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 337: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

This exact project runs just fine on my desktop (Intel Quad 3.7 GHZ + 16GB RAM). Is that an Hardware issue or software (Docker on MAC or Ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Docker RAM Setup]

I found the solution - apparently Docker for MAC uses different Settings or the percentage of given RAM wasn´t enough on this computer.

See picture, setting it to 4GB for a 1GB Dump seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some large insert statements that are bigger than the max size set up in the docker container.

The MySQL startup configuration is specified in the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` of the container.

Try to mimic your local configuration into the docker's one in case there are any differences.

Comment: I used the same build on my other computer, so it should not be a problem of max_size and I already set it to 16M (max_allowed_packet) after having this issue.